# Do Kolagan Warmonger and Recruitment Officer place cards on the bottom of the library if nothing is revealed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Both [Kolagan Warmonger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kolagan%20Warmonger) and [Recruitment Officer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Recruitment%20Officer) have an ability that says to look at the top 6 and 4 cards from the library, then you can show a card matching a condition from among them and put it in hand, and finally put the rest at the bottom of the library.

If I don't show any card, because there is nome or simply not wanting to, must I return all the cards to the top or to the bottom of the library? I think it is the bottom because there are cards that explicitly say "if you do" and this two cards don't, but I'd like to understand the correct way to play these cards.

Comment: [Kolaghan Warmonger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=615410), I presume.

Answer (score 4):

"The rest" refers to all of the cards that weren't revealed. If no cards were revealed, then "the rest" means all of the cards you looked at.

Comment: technically the rest refers to the cards that weren't put in your hand and are still part of the library, but they're the same cards in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the text on Kolaghan Warmonger:

> Whenever Kolaghan Warmonger attacks, look at the top six cards of your library. You may reveal a Dragon card from among them and put it into your hand. Put the rest on the bottom of your library in a random order.

There is no part of the card's text that says put the cards on top of your library. If you don't reveal a Dragon card, then you put all six cards (since these are the cards referred to by "the rest") on the bottom of your library in a random order.

Comment: "There is no part of the card's text that says put the cards on top of your library." This is somewhat confusing, because the player does not need to be specifically instructed to leave cards in the zone that they are already in. For example, if a player controls [Sphinx of Jwar Isle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/details.aspx?multiverseid=185709) then they can look at the top of their library, and the cards would remain on top of their library despite there being no instructions specifically telling them to put the card on top.